# A question about Gaussian integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, prime-factorization, gaussian-integers

I am working on the following exercise:

Show that if $p \equiv 1 \mod 4$ then $p$ is not prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, but instead splits as the product of two distinct prime. [Hint: Show that $p|(a^2+1)$ for some $a$; if $p$ remained prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ show that $p|a\pm i$ and obtain a contradiction.]

I have been able to prove that $p|(a^2+1)$ for some $a$. This implies that $a^2 + 1 = pk $ for some integer $k$. In $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, we then have
$$a^2 +1 = (a+i)(a-i) =pk$$
If $p$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, it must divide either $a-i$ or $a+i$. This follows from the fact that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a unique factorization domain. Without loss of generality, suppose that $p|(a+i)$. This implies that $N(p)|N(a+i)$.  That is, $p^2|(a^2+1)$. How does this yield a contradiction?

Comment: Taking complex conjugates, $p$ also divides $a-i$, ...

Comment: Yes, that's true. Is this not possible?

Comment: So then $p$ divides $(a+i)-(a-i)=2i$ ... :)

Comment: Which is a contradiction as this would imply that $2i = p(x+iy)$ for some integers $x,y$, which is impossible. Thank you!

Comment: $a+i=p(u+vi)\implies pv=1$, for some integer $v$.

Comment: See the Theorem in the linked dupe (one of many).